# Over 1700 errors compiling vscode, what is configured incorrectly?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am following the GitHub instructions to contribute to the Visual Studio Code (vscode) project. The instructions I am following are here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute

I am on Windows 10 and therefore following the Windows-specific instructions.

When I run 'npm run watch' after fulfilling the pre-requisites, I get over 1700 errors when it attempts to build.

Sample errors:

```
[16:56:59] Finished 'clean-client' after 3.78 s
[16:56:59] Starting 'watch-client'...
[16:57:25] Error:E:/src/git/vscode/extensions/css/server/src/languageModelCache.ts(22,21): Cannot find name 'Date'.
[16:57:25] Error: E:/src/git/vscode/extensions/css/server/src/languageModelCache.ts(23,15): Cannot find name 'Object'.
[16:57:25] Error: E:/src/git/vscode/extensions/css/server/src/languageModelCache.ts(40,31): Cannot find name 'Date'.
[16:57:25] Error: E:/src/git/vscode/extensions/css/server/src/languageModelCache.ts(44,80): Cannot find name 'Date'.
[16:57:25] Error: E:/src/git/vscode/extensions/css/server/src/languageModelCache.ts(50,22): Cannot find name 'Number'.
```

The full error list is here:
http://pastebin.com/wJgEQ18m

I am trying to find out how to troubleshoot and correct these errors. So far I have not found anything online to point me to what I did wrong in setting things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a bug in the gulp-tsb project, which was just fixed with the commit below.

https://github.com/jrieken/gulp-tsb/commit/ea84a0a16a631410071ae96336ac9f3842ec41b0

Upgrading to the new gulp and typescript tools fixed the problem.